# Flutter FaIcon: What is the website to search for the icons?

Tags: flutter

I use FaIcon

```
const FaIcon(
Icons.favorite,
color: Colors.white,
size: 24,
),
```

But what is the website to search for an icon?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [font_awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons) official website for getting/search the icon. Just search your desired icon and use the appropriate name (provided by font awesome website) of this icon for flutter.

Comment: No, I know fontawesome but the right icon is not there. Just want to know what is the website for FaIcon

Comment: Which icon you do not found?

Comment: This font awesome package is provided by font_awesome_flutter official library documentation.

Comment: I can use: const FaIcon(
Icons.favorite,
...
), or const FaIcon(
                                    FontAwesomeIcons.arrowRight,
                                    ...
                                  ) but for Icons.XXX what is the search icon website?

Comment: To search Icons.XXX icon use google material icon website, the  Icons.XXX inherited from google (material) icons. https://fonts.google.com/icons

Comment: Yes Zakarian, you resolved my problem. Y will be happy to thank you with giving you a vote? How to do this?

Comment: Done Zakarian. Many thank you for you help!

Comment: Thank you. For upvote just click the ▲Icon to the answer.